# Validate unique username or email

Tags: php, pdo, unique-constraint

I have two files, one contains reg_db class, in other i call object of reg_db. I want it to check user input and column in database, to make sure it will be only unique values. And if it's not unique to stop code, with message. For now i dont get anything, var_dump($conn -> uniqueInput($_POST['reg_username'], '`username`')); outputs NULL.
I want the code to be flexible and that i could set which user input to check with which column in database.

```
//reg_db class
class reg_db{
    private $input;
    private $column;

    public function __construct(){

    }

    public function uniqueInput($reg_input, $reg_column){
        $this -> input = $reg_input;
        $this -> column = $reg_column;
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=fail once again;', 'root', '');
        $db_user = $pdo -> prepare('SELECT :column FROM `users` WHERE :column = :input');
        $db_user -> bindParam(':input', $this -> input, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $db_user -> bindParam(':column', $this -> column, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $db_user -> execute();
        $row = $db_user -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($this -> input == $row[$this -> column]){
            die($this -> column . ' ' . $this -> input . ' is already taken');
        }
    }
}

//object of reg_db
$conn = new reg_db();
$conn -> uniqueInput($_POST['reg_username'], '`username`');
```

Comment: Sorry! I'm not able to understand what you exactly try to achieve. Please use other wording. 'THIS is what I have. THIS is what it outputs. THIS is what I want it to output.'

Comment: Binding `:column` will quote `$this->column`, that's not what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just fetch the user by username and check if it's not the one you're updating.

```
class reg_db{
    private $pdo;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=fail once again;', 'root', '');
    }

    public function getUserBy($reg_column, $reg_input){
        $db_user = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `$reg_column` = :input");
        $db_user->bindParam(':input', $reg_input, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $db_user->execute();
        return $db_user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }
}

$conn = new reg_db();
$user = $conn->getUserBy('username', $_POST['reg_username']);
if ($user && $user->id != $_POST['reg_id']) {
    die("Username '{$_POST['reg_username']}' is already taken");
}
```